# Angular Separate Animation for each element

Tags: angular, animation

I wrote this code but it animate all objects in component together like a group, but I want to animate all elements in *ngFor one after another, Start showing first and after 1 sec next, etc...

angular version : 4.2.5

Here is my code:

**in Component:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of posts; index as i" class="col-lg-4" [@flyInOut]>
    <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{featuredmedias[i]}}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="160" height="160">
    <h2>{{item.title.rendered}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.excerpt.rendered | removeParagrapHtmlTags}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" routerLink="\{{item.slug}}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
```

**in .ts file:**

```
animations: [
trigger('flyInOut', [
  transition('void => *', [
    style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}),
    animate('0.9s ease-in')
  ])
])
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add them one by one instead at once

in component

```
public index: number = 0;

constructor() {
   this.addNext();
}

addNext() {
  if(this.index < this.posts.length) {
     this.showPosts = this.showPosts.concat([this.posts[this.index++]]);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of showPosts; index as i" class="col-lg-4" (@flyInOut.done)="addNext()" [@flyInOut]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the stagger function in the animation DSL, as per the docs: https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger

This is from the docs, as SO don't like answers to be standalone.

In the example below there is a container element that wraps a list of items stamped out by an ngFor. The container element contains an animation trigger that will later be set to query for each of the inner items.

```
<!-- list.component.html -->
<button (click)="toggle()">Show / Hide Items</button>
<hr />
<div [@listAnimation]="items.length">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Cmoponent code

```
import {trigger, transition, style, animate, query, stagger} from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'list.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
       //...
    ])
  ]
})
class ListComponent {
  items = [];

  showItems() {
    this.items = [0,1,2,3,4];
  }

  hideItems() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  toggle() {
    this.items.length ? this.hideItems() : this.showItems();
  }
}
```

Actual animation code

```
trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
    query(':leave', [
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ]),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ])
])
```